# Shadowing of Inherited ADO.Net DataRow Classes is Ignored

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, ado.net, dataset

In an effort to deal with the infamous limitation of ADO.Net datasets that causes StrongTypingExceptions when column values are null, I tried cobbling together a solution based on the suggestions of the user named Suncat in [this comprehensive blog post](http://www.mikewilson.cc/2008/03/18/allow-null-values-to-be-returned-from-strongly-typed-datasets/). That solution was in turn based on [Danila Korablin's sample C# code in this deleted Microsoft Connect thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20110120073554/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/284009/nullable-types-for-typed-dataset). The strong typing exceptions occur when null values are passed into the Property Get and Set statements associated with each column in the dataset; the problem is that Microsoft baked StrongTypingExceptions right into the code generated by the dataset designer, which has caused .Net users nothing but misery for the past decade, including those still maintaining old code. Suncat and Korablin's approach was to create new surrogate properties that allow nulls inside Partial Class statements for the DataRows that own those columns. This drawback of this workaround is that it clutters the DataRow definitions with nullable doubles of those columns, so I tried to improve on it the other day by simply inheriting the dataset and declaring their replacement Nullable columns as Shadows, in an effort to hide the StrongTypingExceptions thrown in the original property definitions. The problem I ran into is that my Shadows properties seem to be ignored; unless I delete the original property declaration from the designer altogether, they're never called.

In the sample code below, the table name is ConnectionTable, the column/property is named MyRate and my original designer-generated dataset is ProjectsDataSet, which is inherited by a new dataset named InheritingDataSet. If I bind a WPF datagrid or whatever to a CollectionViewSource hooked up to the InheritingDataSet instead of its base, everything loads just fine - until I call one of the strongly typed properties in code, in which case the original dataset's version of the property is called, along with the offending exception handler on null values. My nullable Shadows version is never called, *unless* I manually delete the original designer-generated version, which I find quite strange.

Here's the original designer generated property code:

```
    <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), _
     Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")> _
    Public Property MyRate() As Long
        Get
            Try
                Return CType(Me(Me.tableConnectionTable.MyRateColumn), Object)
            Catch e As Global.System.InvalidCastException
                Throw New Global.System.Data.StrongTypingException("The value for column 'MyRate' in table 'ConnectionTable' is DBNul" & _
                        "l.", e)
            End Try
        End Get
        Set(value As Long)
            Me(Me.tableConnectionTable.MyRateColumn) = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Here's the code where I inherit the original. The GetProperty and SetProperty functions are just helper classes designed to cut down on the amount of code I'll need to write if I end up needing hundreds of these shadowed nullable properties; if I take them out, the results are the same.

```
Partial Public Class InheritingDataSet
Inherits ProjectsDataSet


Partial Public Shadows Class ConnectionTableRow

    Private InternalMyRate As Double
    Public Shadows Property MyRate() As Double?
        Get
            Return GetProperty(InternalMyRate)
        End Get
        Set(value As Double?)
            InternalMyRate = value 
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
Public Shared Function GetProperty(value)
    If value Is Nothing OrElse NullCheck(value) = True Then
        Return Nothing
    Else
        Return value 
    End If
End Function
Public Shared Function SetProperty(value)
    If value Is Nothing Then
        Return Global.System.Convert.DBNull 
    Else
        Return value 
    End If
End Function
End Class
```

I don't use inheritance often, so it is possible that I'm doing something wrong in my declarations. I've tried removing the Shadows keyword from the ConnectionTableRow declaration, as well as shadowing the parent table, to no avail. Interestingly enough, if I change Shadows to Overrides, the compiler gives me an error stating that my property "cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a property in a base class." I cannot fathom why the compiler apparently cannot find the property in the base dataset. I also noticed that for some reason, the Source properties of the CollectionViewSources I used with the InheritingDataset (all of which are done entirely in XAML) have their Dataset properties set to InheritingDataset, but curiously, the Dataset properties on the DataTable associated with the CollectionVieWsource views for some reason default to ProjectsDataSet. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can make this work? After all of these years, there really aren't any good, succinct solutions for the StrongTypingException issue, so if I can make this happen, it could be beneficial to a lot of people who still maintain these old .Net datasets. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is certainly not that the compiler can't find the property.  I'd guess that, for whatever reason, it's going through a reference of base class type and thus calling the base class method rather than the derived class shadow method.  I'm not familiar with the specific things that you're using, so I can't say why that is, or what you can do about it.  I do think that your comment about Source and Dataset properties looks like it may be on the right track.

Comment: Thanks Craig, I'll look into that. In the mean time I found an alternate way to deal with the StrongTypingException that only takes a few mouse clicks and doesn't involve inheriting the dataset or shadowing its members, so I'm mulling deleting this post. On the other hand, it could be useful to have an answer, in case this strange behavior pops up again sometime.